# Does vmovd have avx-sse transition penalty?

Tags: assembly, avx

(Assuming there are many avx instructions before and after movd)If I use vmovd to move data between general purpose registers and ymm registers, does it get slower because of using only 1 float value of ymm?

Comment: Can you elaborate? The avx-sse transition penalty only applies when you execute non-VEX encoded SSE instructions and SSE-encoded instructions. As long as you use `vmovd` instead of, say, `movd`, everything should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. That was what I need. I'm writing some inline-asm in C++ that uses avx intrinsics around it.

Comment: Consider using only intrinsics and scrap the inline assembly. The compiler is typically very good in choosing instructions that avoid this sort of penalty.

Comment: But compiler is good at re-ordering things that I want to be untouched(such as kahan addition in the code block that I use vmovd)

Comment: It shouldn't touch your Kahan addition unless you compile with dangerous flags like `-Ofast`.

Comment: I want this compiler-safe and all optimization-safe and need without slowness of "volatile"

Comment: If your compiler conforms to the C standard, it must not “optimize” floating point operations. No need for inline assembly, just make sure you don't compile with options that tell the compiler to ignore the C standard (like `-Ofast`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The avx-sse transition penalty only applies when you execute non-VEX encoded SSE instructions and SSE-encoded instructions. As long as you use `vmovd` instead of, say, `movd`, everything should be fine.